# How can I define separate hazelcast.yaml for testing in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I am writing some integration test and I need to define different TTL for testing. In my app TTL is 7 days, but I want to use 2 sec TTL in my tests. How can I implement two different properties? My app written in Spring boot

Answer (score 1):

Put the overriding YAML in `src/test/resources`. It will shadow `src/main/resources`. Con: you'll need to duplicate all of the first YAML properties.

Alternatively, you can [override specific parameters](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/configuration/overriding-configuration-settings) using either System properties or environment variables.